# table view save user input data after exiting app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app which uses table view controller. I am able to save and show the data in the table view, but once I am exiting the app, it loses the information and the table becomes empty. I am new to iOS development, any help will be highly appreciated.

I have added the *AddReminderViewController* and *RemindersTableViewController*  files. I am really new to this, so please can you tell me the codes i have to add in 'aplicationDidEnterBackground' to save the data. Thank you all who already helped me so quickly.

## AddReminderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddReminderViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

@end
```

## AddReminderViewController.m

```
#import "AddReminderViewController.h"

@interface AddReminderViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddReminderViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.itemText.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
[self.itemText resignFirstResponder];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

// Dismiss the view controller
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.itemText resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}

@end
```

## RemindersTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RemindersTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

## RemindersTableViewController.m

```
#import "RemindersTableViewController.h"


@interface RemindersTableViewController ()
- (void)reloadTable;

@end

@implementation RemindersTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                             name:@"reloadData"
                                           object:nil];
 }



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Get list of local notifications
NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Display notification info
[cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];

return cell;
}



- (void)reloadTable
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}




#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Comment: `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}`

Send here notification to save your data

Comment: @user2545330 that method is basically never called now...

Comment: `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}` called when you press home button, or lock screen

Comment: actually its like a to-do app, where the user enters the data. So -(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{} ... can be helpful??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers,     and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added the files. Can you please tell me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use one of `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` and `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` to save data.

you can get data back in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added the files. Can you please tell me the code?

Comment: NSString *dataToSave = @"someValue";[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dataToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize] and get back  NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{NSString *dataToSave = @"someValue";[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dataToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]} ......... and  .....- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];}.....like that???